# What are the ways to say that I was in a place without the possibility to connect with my phone?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-usage, sentence-request

What the ways to say that I was in a place without possibility to connect with my phone?

For example in such situation:

> **Wife**: Why did you not answer my call when I called you?"
>
> **Husband**: "I was in a place without connection"(?) / or "I didn't have
>   connection"

In my language we say: "I didn't have signal /reception /range /coverage" or "I was in area without signal /reception /range /coverage. (I'm not sure about the accurate term of each one of them for translation).

In the meantime I found somethings but I'm not sure about their usage if any:

- I was in a dead zone for cell phones.
- I was in radio shadow.
- I was in a non-serviced area

Comment: 'Catchy'? No. I don't know where you got that from! The others would all be understood. We'd typically say "I couldn't get a signal" or "a connection" (note the indefinite article). 'An area with no coverage' maybe sounds a little formal but is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Catchy is my mistake (based on a dictionary) and I omited it.

Comment: In my circles, it's usually "I didn't have any service" or "I didn't have any signal"

Comment: @StephenS In my circle it's usually "I didn't have any bars". :)

Answer (score 4):

I think *I was in a dead zone*  is a good option in this context.

In my opinion, *service* is a commonly used word here. I think *reception* is also common. *Coverage* is possible, but I think it's not a common option. It sounds closer to the terms outline in your cell phone plan. *A signal* and *a connection* are also possible. *Range* is not really possibly by itself (maybe something like *I was not within signal range*, but that seems clunky to me).

Here are a few patterns you could follow:

> 1. I had no service.
> 2. I didn't have any service.
> 3. There was no service (where I was).
> 4. I was in a place with no service.

Answer (score 2):

There's many, many ways to express this.

> I had no bars.
>
> No service there.
>
> I was out of range.
>
> There was no coverage.
>
> I was out of roaming.
>
> There was no signal.
>
> I have Sprint. (jk ;)
>
> The closes tower is like 10 miles away.